# Redis SET fails when value has spaces

Tags: string, redis, space

I just fired up Redis and am playing around with it. The following works fine:

```
SET billybob "hello"
+OK
```

However, the following fails:

```
SET billybob "hey how are you"
-ERR syntax error
```

I thought SET worked for any key/value, and presumably a value can be any string... but not a string with spaces? What's the story here?

Comment: What version of redis? What platform? Are you just running commands via redis-cli?

Comment: works for me from `redis-cli` with `redis_version:2.9.7`

Comment: the same valid SET command will fail when piped to `redis-cli --pipe` BTW (but succeeds in redis-cli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is version related. This here works:

```
$ redis-cli --version
redis-cli 2.8.3

$ redis-cli SET billybob "hey how are you"
OK

$ redis-cli GET billybob
"hey how are you"
```

@jm3
Use the '-x' command line option for the redis-cli instead. 
Beware that it will add a "\n" at the end of your string:

```
$ echo "hey how are you"
hey how are you

$ echo "hey how are you" | redis-cli --pipe SET billybob
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
ERR unknown command 'hey'
Last reply received from server.
errors: 1, replies: 1

$ echo "hey how are you" | redis-cli -x SET billybob
OK
$ redis-cli GET billybob
"hey how are you\n"
```

HTH

bernie

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your are running commands in telnet. Basically, redis implements text-based commands based on a low level text protocol, a request/reply may contains multiple text lines prefixed special characters such as $ *, or characters prefixed with its length.

And for convenience, redis also support **inline commands**:

> For this reason Redis also accepts commands in a special way that is designed for humans, and is called the inline command format. (see [here](http://redis.io/topics/protocol))

The first command your typed is a **inline command**, it works. The second one has spaces so not a **inline command**, then broken.

So you could use inline command to send the set command with spaces:

```
*3
$3
set
$8
billybob
$15
hey how are you
+OK
```

[Reidis protocol documentation](http://redis.io/topics/protocol)

Comment: a suggestion on how to actually fix this would be helpful; the OP already knows it doesn't work.

Comment: I just answered the OP's questions, " What's the story here? "